# What's the proof that Karma is doing its job?

Tags: karma, practice, rebirth

I am not that much of a religion virtuoso you will excuse my `materialistic` reasoning plane  We keep being told that `Karma` will catch with you . `Good Karma and Bad Karma` are  awarded appropriately  etc and we take birth to live through our Karmic backlog ( unless we are a divine soul level who choose if they want to be born or not. They dont have net Karma that'll call them )  this nutshell is being conceptualized at various levels and expressed various ways.

But observation runs 180 opp theory. For more than 2000+ yrs Hindoos , from Kashmiri Pandits to Mopalas to Assam / Kerala Hindus are being ethnically cleansed so were Christians in Lebanon, Armenia Syria and Jews in Arabia  and Europe . The people who run this world are the biggest sinners. In fact the bigger you are a sinner the more you control the world. Some will say `kalyuga` time - that was expected and ya da ya . But Karma should hold through all the passages of time ?
If Karma has done it's job how come e.g.

--A mass murderer and pedophile so called prophet who  rapes women , commits incest  and  keeps sex slaves calls himself  so called "messenger of God" and creates a  bestial cult ,forces the world to recognize it as a religion and that religion imposes itself by force in every part of the world ( civilized or third world ) committing acts of  terror .  And the world recognizes that cult as a Semitic Religion ?  Individual people maybe good but I am talking of the philosophy  of that mass murderers cult

--Colonialists  looted colonies in Africa North America Asia and committed forced conversions ( even though Christianity itself is a peaceful religion and Jesus was an Avtaar that never  said enforce your  religion on others ) that take place even today

-- Marble mouth politicians in democracies ditch the middle class that voted them in - want to be enslaved and exploited and wallow in corruption and create minority vote banks all over the world

Where is Karma ? Deferred to next birth ? yeah so then Gods or   Karmic or Divine or whatever design was in place that defers your karma to next birth ... isn't that a fraudulent design ? because the sinner  is given incentive to keep doing sins ? ( don't worry son - keep doing the most debauched things in this life. We will  send you a bill in your next life. Sinner chuckles - what next life hehe ) .  Based on this I am  forced the conclude that :

-- Karma is not potent and powerful enough to do its job
It gives a nice bail out package to  sinners e.g. the fake prophet who called himself messenger of God or Stalin  or Hitler or Gandhi ( all of them had comfortable lives and died  without all the torture that they created for others )

-- Someone Bribed Karma

-- Karmic reservation System
only if you beleive in Karma and keep conscience will Karma affect you . So its a reservation system in place. No  Karma for peaceful religion terrorists like D Company but Karma for small acts of greed done by people who have conscience in their within

If Karma bad Karma was retributed  in this birth itself sinners wont sin because regardless of whether they have conscience - they know there will be payback time in this birth itself.

So here's a small poem I wrote to express my question. Hope you enjoy it and gimme and equally enjoyable answer !

```
**The Irony of Karma** 

Karma, ancient wisdom we hold dear,
Balancing wrongs and rights, it's clear.
But in this   world of sin and vice,
Does Karma truly bring ⚖️ justice, precise?

Mass murderers and pedophiles calling themselves prophets roam free,
Starting cults, spreading dread with glee.
They claim to be "messengers of God" ,
Forcing beliefs with an iron rod.

Them Liberal & 'Sick-U-Liar'  Politicians deceive with practiced ease,
Colonialists plunder, as they please.
Where does Karma reside in this land  ?
Bribed   or overpowered ️‍♂️, it seems unplanned.

Or is there a Karmic   "reservation system"    that  excludes  those without  a conscience,
So they can  continue their nonsense?
If Karma struck in this present life,
Sinners might think twice before causing strife.

And so this "Karmic suffering"  lingers on  ⤴️♻️⤵️ , 
In the next birth, where sinners are drawn,
Unaware they pay for past misdeeds,
A cycle unending, no solace it breeds.

But why does the   Divine decree such fate,
In the next birth, where sinners await?
Unaware they pay for their past transgressions,
The cycle persists, no end in succession.

Some say it's the time of Kalyuga,
When evil thrives, and virtue's fewer.
Should not Karma persist throughout time,
Punishing the wicked for their crime?

Perhaps Hindus have forgotten their Dharma,
as they keep thinking of Karma 
To seek retribution, reclaim what was stolen,
From  those "Religion Of Peace" monsters who practice hate,
Forced conversions and lands they confiscate.

Yet until then, we can only ponder,
If Karma wields true power, or we wander.
```

Comment: There is no materialistic proof of karma and I do not think it will ever be shown. Secondly, your opinion is really drastic especially towards Islam. I do not think that is allowed on this stackexchange.

Comment: I have given examples not just Hindus but other religions too . I have not used any religion in my description where I throw disdain  - so I refute such allegations. That maybe your perception.  Far as Islam is concerned - that word does not exist anywhere in my writing. But having said that you cannot cover up facts by trying to be  politically correct while  not allowing factually correct historical cites and my  question on Karma is related to such historical  injustices

Comment: But it pains me if as a Hindu you do not accept the culprits of the largest and longest ethnic cleansing effort that started more than  1400 years ago and is still going  on. Nothing is my option btw its all facts.

Comment: Then answer me this. What is the name of this prophet who is according to you a mass murder and pedophile?

Comment: can be anyone. Its important that I have named No One in my question  first to make sure that I adhere to Stacks policies which I am aware  and 2) to keep off  Gandhari types ( `Gandhari`  one who can sees but pretends not to see - that is the analogy no other extension of it  )  .But if you choose to associate if with some specific person  then in fact that is  admission of guilt of  that persons wrong doings in the first place & it vindicates whatever you said of him,.Something that is done by you and not me..

Comment: BTW  I fully empathize and  want to fund people like Geert Wilders  the more I run across Gandhari kind of persons. I pray to `Jesus Moses and Bhagwan` that  the peaceful  beautiful land where he resides should give him a chance to come to power.

Comment: I do not think karma is as easily implemented as you think it is. It is a automatic complex system with different variations.

Comment: that I understand perfectly - but when we start discussing a topic we have to scratch the surface first and talk about it in a simple manner . but surely  2000 yrs isn't a time really miniscule for Karma to get its act together and show humanity that yes it exists and there will be   `karnic retribution` if that happens then people will not have any incentive to commit Sin .

Answer (score 1):

in the law book of kali yuga "parasar smriti" chapter 1 verse 30 it has been written that 'in kali yuga dharma will be deafeated by adharma, satya by asatya, kings by thieves and men will be overpowered by women'. that is why you are seeing the victory of falsehood over truth. every yuga have a different features. you are seeing good people are suffering and bad people are enjoying. there is a story in the puranas that there were 2 beggars one devotee and other sinful. one day the devotee got one finger of his leg cut and the sinful beggar got a gold coin. naradji  asked the reason to lord krishna. he said that as per previous karma the devotee beggar was destined to loose his entire leg  but due to devotion his punishment has been reduced to the loss of one finger. he also said that the sinful beggar was destined to become a king in this birth but due to his sins his rewards have been reduced to a single gold coin. in mahabharata the pandavas had to suffer whole life inspite of being good while kauravas enjoyed while being sinful. why? in (Gita chapter 18 moksha yoga) it has been written those who do sattvic karma they get poison in the beginning and nectar in the end. ' agre visam eva pariname amritapam'. and those who do rajasic karma they get nectar first and poison later. so the kauravas enjoyed first and suffered later and pandavas suffered first and enjoyed later.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146813/discussion-on-answer-by-arunava-biswas-whats-the-proof-that-karma-is-doing-it-j); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.